# What is the longest C line-of-code using unique ASCII characters?

Tags: c, syntax, ascii, lexical

This challenge gets to to some of the subtle aspects of the C language.  My first stab at this follows.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i;
  int f[1];
  double A,B,C,D,EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_;
  // Following line is a line using many ASCII characters.  (Begins with a TAB)
    {a =!~(0*b%c^d&e+f[g]|h-i)?A:B>C,D<EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_/1.23456789;}
  // Failed to use \ ` @ # $ " ' : and various control characters.
  return (0);
}
```

How can I use `\ backquote @ # $ " ' :` and maybe some more control characters?

Background: in creating code checkers and beautifiers, we run into various subtle C language issues.  The above is a group self imposed exercise.

Note: ASCII is characters codes 0 - 127.
Note: Strings normally use pairs of quote marks and the line is limited to unique usages.

Comment: \ could be used with `\u` (universal, i.e. Unicode, character, which can occur in identifiers outside quotes) but I can't see any way you could use the others you listed just once. And you already used `:`.

Comment: You used '0' twice, but you simply have to remove the second '0' (in `0.123456789`) to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can put everything in a string, and go to the next line with a `\` :

```
void main() {
  int a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,f[1];
  double A,B,C,D,EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_;
  // Following line is a line using many ASCII characters.  (Begins with a TAB)
    {a =!~(0*b%c^d&e+f[g]|h-i)?A:B>C,D<EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_/1.23456789;}"'`@#$\
 ";
}
```

Comment: Using `'` twice is not permitted; each character can be used only once.

Comment: One could argue of course whether using \ followed by a newline counts the newline and following line as "part of the line".

Comment: As this is a creative challenge, there is little hard rules, but I would think that once a newline occurs (or maybe vertical tab, form feed), that's the end of the line.

Comment: @chux if so, the current answer fits perfectly. but you cannot escape anything inside the string.

Comment: @Elazar A variation on your answer looks workable.  The string you suggested is not in the equation, but that's easy to fix.  Also I do not think a `'` can be used in a string without a `\\`.  I wonder what compliant compilers do with various odd characters like \a, \b which I think are white spaces.

Comment: @chux this code compiles correctly. there is no need to escape `'` in a string literal. What does "The string you suggested is not in the equation" mean?

Comment: @Elazar - 1) I always thought one needed to escape `'` in a string literal.  So I learned something new.  2) The string you suggested is not part of the a = ... equation, that threw me off as begin legit.  I double checked and see that you simple have an string after the equation - which appears to be legal, but unusual code.  Of course, unusual code is OK here.

Comment: What about putting everything in a comment instead, and terminating the comment on the next line?

Comment: or putting everything in a string. or between `#if 0` and `#endif`... it isn't fun :) .

Comment: @R..  Good, but it was to be a "C line-of-code" and where I work, comments don't count as lines-of-code.